# How to set_xticklabels to corresponding "dates" column of a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, axis-labels

**The issue**

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns of data and corresponding date times in another column. I want to make a line plot for the two sets of data and have the date times, which is a list of strings, as the x-axis tick labels. But when I make the plot, the tick labels don't align with the corresponding data for that date. Instead the xlabels just come from the first n entries of the dates column.

My original program had a tick at every data point, so I tried setting ax.set_xticks to reduce the number of ticks, and that's when this issue arose.

**The code**

```
import numpy             as     np
import datetime
import pandas            as     pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as     plt
% matplotlib inline

data = { 'Set1': np.random.rand(24),
         'Set2': np.random.rand(24)
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Set1','Set2'])

date_list = []
base = datetime.datetime(2000,1,1,0)
for i in range(len(df.Set1)):
    date = base + datetime.timedelta(hours=i*3)
    date_frmt = date.strftime("%b%d%Hz")
    date_list.append(str(date_frmt))
df['Dates'] = date_list

print(df)
```

> ```
>     Set1      Set2      Dates
> 0   0.521824  0.371057  Jan0100z
> 1   0.726503  0.945712  Jan0103z
> 2   0.881100  0.725798  Jan0106z
> 3   0.432198  0.549191  Jan0109z
> 4   0.083255  0.297057  Jan0112z
> 5   0.428145  0.441973  Jan0115z
> 6   0.168049  0.411889  Jan0118z
> 7   0.654588  0.822227  Jan0121z
> 8   0.540984  0.824515  Jan0200z
> 9   0.999410  0.809121  Jan0203z
> 10  0.055359  0.901241  Jan0206z
> 11  0.163407  0.085901  Jan0209z
> 12  0.523488  0.011856  Jan0212z
> 13  0.133038  0.881413  Jan0215z
> 14  0.880946  0.301656  Jan0218z
> 15  0.575265  0.972408  Jan0221z
> 16  0.489332  0.399983  Jan0300z
> 17  0.119246  0.216152  Jan0303z
> 18  0.805346  0.873699  Jan0306z
> 19  0.806190  0.277772  Jan0309z
> 20  0.868357  0.311854  Jan0312z
> 21  0.042386  0.461695  Jan0315z
> 22  0.354832  0.262534  Jan0318z
> 23  0.209049  0.780153  Jan0321z
> ```

```
 ax = df.plot(figsize=(10, 5))
 ax.set_xticklabels(df.Dates)
```

[image]

**The problem**

How do I get the ticks' labels to align correctly with their corresponding data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this line after `ax = df.plot(figsize=(10, 5))`:

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(df.shape[0])[::1], df.Dates[::1], rotation=35)
```

The indexing part `[::1]` lets you pick at which interval you want to put them (here all of them, but it will be cluttered). So you won't need this line `ax.set_xticklabels(df.Dates)`.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this using "ax." notation instead of plt.?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pyplot's `DateFormatter`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for col in ['Set1', 'Set2']:
    ax.plot(df['Dates'], df[col], label=col)

ax.legend()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b%d%Hz'))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I think this is off by one index value
. I get "ValueError: could not convert string to float: Jan0321z"

Comment: You still need to do `df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'],format='%b%d%Hz')` before my solution.

Comment: This does work for the example shown here. However, if I decide to change my ticklabels to a mmdd format and leave off the time, the plot changes accordingly, plotting all 8 data entries from that day on that day's first x-axis value in a short, vertical line, as if they were all at 00z. The other solution doesn't do this, so I consider it more robust.

Comment: Here you can always change the format inside `DateFormatter()` as you wish. The other solution won’t help you much if you have, say, hundreds of rows. And also, it won’t scale the time properly if you have uneven time steps. But you can always choose what best fit for you.